# add same fragment in the same framelayout activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I want to add dynamic inputs using one fragment, this fragment includes one input and everytime that I click the button the fragment will be insert in the activity layout,
actually I can do it but when I click the button for the second time it's add the fragment input but is overlaps with de old fragment input

inputFragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.InputFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/contInput"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:hint="Usuario"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/cont"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".controller.Activity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="324dp"
    android:layout_height="81dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
    android:text="Insert input"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment_container"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="414dp"
    android:layout_height="289dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-2dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout >
```

activity.kt

```
  class Activity : AppCompatActivity(){

    private var myList =  ArrayList<InputFragment>()
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val binding = ActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        
        binding.btn.setOnClickListener {
           
            val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager

            val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            val nuevoFragmento = InputFragment()

            fragmentTransaction.add (R.id.fragment_container, nuevoFragmento)
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
            fragmentTransaction.commit()

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not achievable with fragments, when a new fragment is added to the fragment container, the old will not be visible. I will suggest using something that allows list based views such as the Recyclerview. But for a simple small number of inputs, manually hiding inputs and toggling the visibility is the simplest solution

Comment: In my case i want to keep the old fragment, the main idea is create a dynamic form

Comment: From what I understood, "dynamic" here means you want to make the screen show more input fields when the button is clicked. This can also be achieved in the same fragment without the need to use the fragment container. Simply adding more TextInputLayout, making them invisble and showing them when they are needed is enough. You can animate more complex interactions as needed this way too

Comment: yes you got it, I set the add fragment functionality in the button just for explain my problem in an easy way, in fact and endpoint will return the information about how many inputs that i need to draw